# Properties of Sigma sum

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem

I am trying to prove that

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{l} \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{l-k} = \binom{n+m}{l} $$
> use $(1+x)^{n}(1+x)^{m}$.

The book suggests the following solution

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{m} \binom{m}{j} x^{j}
> = \sum_{l=0}^{n+m} \binom{n+m}{l} x^{l}$$
> where

> $$x^{l} = \sum_{k=0}^{l} \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{l-k}$$

I understand the idea of how the formula to prove it makes sense, but I cannot finish wrapping my head around why $x^{l}$ has that value. Then again, I understand its value and how it fits, but not how I could deduce such value on my own in another exercise.

I am looking for help finishing my proof, but I am not looking for an intuitive way to understand it or an alternative answer to my attempt. I would appreciate very much if somebody would help me figure out if my idea is right, or if not, what I am missing. My attempt goes as follows:

$$(1+x)^{n}(1+x)^{m}= \sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} x^{r} \sum_{s=0}^{m} \binom{m}{s} x^{s}$$
Now, lets define l as $l=r+s$, such that $s=l-r$, so we have

$$= \sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} x^{r} \sum_{l-r=0}^{m} \binom{m}{l-r} x^{l-r}$$
$$= \sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{l-r=0}^{m} \binom{m}{l-r} x^{l-r} \binom{n}{r} x^{r} $$

And this is where I am stuck. The only way I can turn this into the correct answer is by saying

$$= \sum_{r+l-r=0}^{n+m} \binom{n+m}{r-l-r} x^{r-l-r} =                            
  \sum_{l=0}^{n+m} \binom{n+m}{l} x^{l}$$
by saying that the sum of the terms $x^{l}$ is equivalent to
$x_{r_{1}}(x_{s_{1}}+x_{s_{2}}+...) + 
x_{r_{2}}(x_{s_{1}}+x_{s_{2}}+...) + 
x_{r_{3}}(x_{s_{1}}+x_{s_{2}}+...) + ...$

Is that equivalence correct? If that is not right, how can I turn my attempt into the right answer? How can I know the value of $x^{l}$ just by looking at the solution from the book since that it seems to suggest it is obvious?

Comment: If the book really says $$x^l=\sum\dots$$ then the book is wrong. The sum is equal to the coefficient of $x^l$ on the left side, not to $x^l.$

Comment: I made a mistake writting that. It is corrected now

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What can I do for it to be right? I am really stuck trying to solve this one. I don't get how to turn those sums into just a term

Comment: The trick, and what @ThomasAndrews is pointing out, is to analyse the coefficients of the product of two power series. See e.g. [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series), though I imagine (hope?) that this has been discussed in your book somewhere too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your derivation:

> Now, lets define l as $l=r+s$, such that $s=l-r$, so we have
> \begin{align*}
> \ldots = \sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} x^{r} \sum_{\color{blue}{l-r=0}}^{\color{blue}{m}} \binom{m}{l-r} x^{l-r}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

it is the index region in the inner sum (1) which needs to be revised. Note, from (1) we obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=0}^{n}& \binom{n}{r} x^{r} \sum_{\color{blue}{l=r}}^{\color{blue}{m}} \binom{m}{l-r} x^{l-r}\tag{1.1}\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{\color{blue}{l=r}}^{\color{blue}{m}} \binom{m}{l-r} x^{l-r} \binom{n}{r} x^{r}\tag{1.2}\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{\color{blue}{l=r}}^{\color{blue}{m}} \binom{m}{l-r} \binom{n}{r} x^{l}\tag{1.3}\\
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1.1) we use a more common notation to write the lower limit of the inner sum without changing anything else
- In (1.2) we follow your next step
- In (1.3) we collect the terms in $x$ and get $x^{l-r}x^r = x^{(l-r)+r}=x^l$.

We observe in (1.3) the expression is a polynomial in $x$ with degree $\leq m$ since $r\leq l \leq m$. But we know from
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^n(1+x)^m=(1+x)^{n+m}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
the degree of the polynomial in $x$ in (2) is $\color{blue}{n+m}$. So, something was wrong.

> In fact when substituting $l=r+s$ we have to respect the valid *index range* of the newly introduced index variable $l$. We have
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left.\begin{array}{l}
> 0\leq r \leq n\\
> 0\leq s\leq m
> \end{array}\right\}
> \qquad\to\qquad 0\leq r+s=l\leq n+m}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> We see the index range of $l$ is not $r\leq l\leq m$ as used in (1.1) to (1.3) but $0\leq l\leq n+m$ instead as stated in (3). With this correction we are on the right track again, since now we can write
> \begin{align*}
> (1+x)^n(1+x)^m&=\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} x^{r} \sum_{s=0}^{m} \binom{m}{s} x^{s}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{s=0}^m\binom{n}{r}\binom{m}{s}x^{r+s}\\
> &=\sum_{l=0}^{m+n}\left(\sum_{{r+s=l}\atop{r\geq 0, s\geq 0}}\binom{n}{r}\binom{m}{s}\right)x^l\tag{3.1}\\
> &=\sum_{l=0}^{m+n}\left(\sum_{r=0}^{l}\binom{n}{r}\binom{m}{l-r}\right)x^l\tag{3.2}\\
> \end{align*}
> Since we have $(1+x)^n(1+x)^m=(1+x)^{n+m}=\sum_{l=0}^{n+m}\binom{n+m}{l}x^l$ the claim follows by coefficient comparison with (3.2) of alike powers in $x$.

*Comment:*

- In (3.1) we introduce $l=r+s$ and rearrance the polynomial according increasing powers of $l$.
- In (3.2) we eliminate $r$ using $r=l-s$.

Comment: Thank you!
I did not check this site for a while and I missed your answer.

Thank you for being so clear with the right path I should follow, but even more for point exactly where my logic was wrong.

Comment: @ManuelMares: You're welcome! Good to see my answer is useful. :-)